# How to remove certain rows from a list in R?

Tags: r

My document is formatted like this (though it is much longer)

```
1     1
1     2
2     1
1     3
3    10
10    5
5    16
16    8
```

And is constructed using this:

```
xlist<-read.table("Tree.txt")
```

How do I remove specific rows from this data set?
I want to remove every row that begins with 1.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Use logical indexing:

```
xlist <- xlist[xlist[[1]] != 1,]
```